# Table cells width dosen't add up correctly on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

This happends on firefox, while working fine on chrome.

Last cell takes more space then it is given to the cell.
All values add up to a complete 100%.

Consider following code:

```
<table style="position: relative;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#E5FFC8;border-top:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-left:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-right:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-bottom:#a6a6a6 1px solid" width="75.68%" height="50px"></td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFC2C2;border-top:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-right:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-bottom:#a6a6a6 1px solid" width="15.03%"></td>
            <td style="background-color:#9EC6FF;border-top:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-right:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-bottom:#a6a6a6 1px solid" width="4.81%"></td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFF99;border-top:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-right:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-bottom:#a6a6a6 1px solid" width="1.83%"></td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFCC99;border-top:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-right:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-bottom:#a6a6a6 1px solid" width="2.46%"></td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFC8EC;border-top:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-right:#a6a6a6 1px solid;border-bottom:#a6a6a6 1px solid" width="0.19%"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is on Chrome: [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7NxC.png)

This is on Firefox: [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umI8r.png)

Tested on Linux, Firefox version: Quantum 66.0.4, Chrome version: 74.0.3729.169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your last line like this.

```
<td style="background-color:#FFC8EC;border-top:1px solid #a6a6a6;border-right:1px solid #a6a6a6;border-bottom:1px solid #a6a6a6; width:0.19% !important" width="0.19%"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! If I specify width in style as`width: 0.19%`, instead of attribute as `width="0.19%"`, it's behaving as expected.

Comment: Yes , specially If we used !important , then it will work fine in both.